# Azure - why can't I find attached drive on my vm?

Tags: azure

I have created a new vm (A0) using the new Azure portal (Resource manager?) and attached a new drive (1023gb) to the vm.

When I RDP to the instance, I can't see the new drive.  I deleted the drive and added one of 20gb as I think that there may be a 20gb limit on drives for A0. Still nothing.

What's up?

Comment: If this is a Windows VM, have partitioned the disk and assigned it a drive letter via Disk Management? If this is a Linux VM, make sure you can see the disk by running "fdisk -l"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please follow the "Initialize a new data disk" section of documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-managed-disk-portal#initialize-a-new-data-disk

Comment: This is for the 'Classic' portal.  I have used (as advised) the new Resource Manager Model, the equivalent link being this:
[https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-attach-disk-preview/](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-attach-disk-preview/)
I have followed this process and have the problem as described above.

Comment: The "How to: initialize a new data disk in Windows Server" section is the same regardless the portal or the deployment model.

Comment: Ah, indeed.  At the end of the page after 'Option 2' it has Next Steps...

Be nice if they alluded to this at the end of 'Option 1' as well.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: These links are currently broken.

Comment: I've fixed the link.

Answer (score -3):

The accepted answer didn't work for me on Linux VM, but this link did: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal#connect-to-the-linux-vm-to-mount-the-new-disk

This shows you how to actually find the disk from the command line in the VM, and mount it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Ok now it has pictures from the link. Though the accepted answer has the same issues mentioned in these comments...